# Problem in Installing Magento 2.3 on Widnow LocalHost

Tags: magento2.3

### **Error:**

1. 404 Error for js file from the pub
2. Wrong path for js. Showing http://localhost//[MAGENTO]jquery.js where it should show http://localhost//[MAGENTO][PUB_PATH]jquery.js

Please see attached images for better ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try to Below Solution.**

1. Open file
   /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php
   and find

> *$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);*

Replace with :

> *$realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));*

2. Open file app/etc/di.xml in magento install dir, find

> *Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink*

Replace with :

> *Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy*